# Node JS Building JSON Buffers

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a Node JS chat server that uses simple JSON messaging to send commands and chat messages between clients. It works great, but I know from previous experience that it is essential to provide, in the least, an end-of-file or end-of-transmission tag.

Because Node has done so much of the server and networking work for me, I don't want to re-invent an existing wheel, but I can't find a great resource about building up Node buffers.

Given a client connects

```
    net.createServer(function(socket){
        socket.setEncoding("utf8");
        var client = self.clientManager.create(socket);
        self._attachDefaultHandlers(client);
    }).listen(this.settings.port);
```

And handlers are attached

```
_attachDefaultHandlers(client){
    client.socket.on('data', function(data){

    });
    client.socket.on('end', function(){

    });
    client.socket.on('close', function(){

    });
    return this;
}
```

How can I build up a buffer to know that a message from the client is complete in regards to the `.on('data')` event? And who is in charge of this buffer - the spawned client or the server? Who manages it?

Comment: Sounds like you should look into socket programming a bit more - nobody "owns" the buffer; once it's transmitted from the client to the server, both of them own their own buffers with a copy of the data. Also, you should probably be using JSON if you're working in Node.js.

Comment: I am using `JSON`. I just know that it is bad practice to assume a message will always get through as a certain size, so you should have end tags. To do that, I need to build buffers, and process them

Comment: Not sure where you got that idea, but it's not a bad idea that a message is assumed to be a certain size. Many application protocols prefix the packet's length to the message prior to sending the message itself. In fact, it's preferred in many cases for optimization reasons.